# jboss error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I'm trying to create a simple hello world java web application that is using JPA through hibernate and using JBoss 6.4.0 as application Server. The application has been created through maven. Furthermore I'm using Intellij as an IDE. However when I run the application Server I receive the following error:

```
16:09:04,772 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
16:09:04,774 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
16:09:04,970 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
16:09:05,141 WARN  [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
16:09:05,145 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb]
16:09:05,146 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=smattes, password=****}
16:09:05,147 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
16:09:05,150 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit.javahelloworld#NewPersistenceUnit: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.javahelloworld#NewPersistenceUnit: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:141)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99)
    ... 4 more

16:09:05,164 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014612: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "javahelloworld")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.javahelloworld#NewPersistenceUnit" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.javahelloworld#NewPersistenceUnit: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V"}}
16:09:05,179 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "javahelloworld.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.javahelloworld#NewPersistenceUnit" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.javahelloworld#NewPersistenceUnit: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V"}}
16:09:05,211 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment javahelloworld (runtime-name: javahelloworld.war) in 42ms
16:09:05,213 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
```

The persistence.xml file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>jpa.AuthorsEntity</class>
        <class>jpa.UserEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="myusername"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="mypassword"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and the jpa.AuthorsEntity and jpa.UserEntity are two java Entity classes that correspond to the tables authors and user correspondingly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such errors are typically caused by having different versions of a library on the compile time and runtime classpath.

Application servers - such as JBoss - typically provide their own versions of the Hibernate libraries at runtime. This version is then most likely incompatible with the compile time version specified in your POM.

JBoss AS 6.4 only supports JPA spec 2. You can then either roll-back the compile time Hibernate version in your POM to be compatible with the runtime dependency supplied by JBoss or, if you really need JPA 2.1 features, tell JBoss you are bundling the Hibernate libraries with your app.

For the former approach, this document indicates EAP 6.4 supports Hibarnate 4.2.18.Final

https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673#EAP_6

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.18.Final</version>
    <!-- Don't bundle in the WAR as provided by the server -->
    <scope>provided</scope> 
</dependency>
```

Check there are no hibernate libs in the deployed war (as a result of transitive dependencies for example).

For the latter approach see here:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-209?_sscc=t

Comment: I tried the first solution and it worked! Furthermore I had to change the persistence.xml from <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider> to <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

Answer (score 0):

for future readers, recently i had this issues, i had in the project the hibernate version 5.1 with glassfish 4.1 and it is generated this issues, for resolved i agregated in the WEB-INF folder the file glassfish-web.xml
as i showing to continuation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
    <class-loader delegate="false"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```